# Постановка тире в неполном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

"Евгений был одет в белую футболку и черные шорты, Александр — так же". Тут будет тире? Я сомневаюсь насчет паузы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире желательно поставить: **Евгений был одет в белую футболку и черные шорты, Александр — так же.**

Тире связано не только с паузой, но и со всей интонацией предложения.

Это предложение состоит **из двух частей разного объема,** и если мы не делаем паузу, то должны первую (длинную) часть произнести в одну фразу, а потом сразу перейти ко второй (короткой) части.  Предложение в этом случае звучит неудобно и невыразительно: **Евгений был одет в белую футболку и черные шОрты,// Александр тАк же.**

Если поставить тире и сделать паузу, то интонация будет параллельной:

**ЕвгЕний был одет //в белую футболку и черные шОрты, АлексАндр — тАк же.**

Здесь мы подчеркиваем противопоставление ***Евгений — Александр,*** но когда повышение голоса делается на слове ***Александр***, после этого обязательно следует пауза.

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в паузе, хотя она и возможна при чтении.

В частях сложного предложения с параллельной структурой на месте пропущенных членов предложения или их частей ставится **тире**. Здесь *пропущено* подразумеваемое "**был одет**".

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=54#pg54

Comment: Дело в интонации, а пауза - это часть интонации.  Есть предложения параллельной структуры, в которых сравниваются две ситуации, но интонация в них может быть параллельной или нет, что зависит от расстановки тонических ударений. У Розенталя эта тема рассматривается и приводятся примеры. Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо. Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93 В обоих случаях  пропущено сказуемое, но тире ставится  в одном.  Поэтому нужно  определять тип интонации, а не просто ориентироваться на пропущенные слова.

Comment: Все примеры Розенталя укладываются в его обобщение _"При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится"._ Этому соответствовало бы предложение: _"Евгений был одет в белую футболку, Александр в чёрную."_ (Интонационный вариант при соотв. контексте: "... - в чёрную!") Но у нас параллелизм разбивается  не только пропущенным "был одет", а и разнородностью членов, указывающих в "во что одет" и "как одет".

Comment: Поэтому тире мне представляется здесь _обязательным_: оно не только замещает пропущенное (которое предлагается домыслить), но и обращает внимание на необходимость установить соответствие между двумя формами. Интонация лишь сопутствует этому как следствие (отсутствие паузы затруднило бы понимание).

Comment: На письме - знаки препинания, в устной речи - интонация, в грамматике - структура, в сообщении - смысл, я это обычно не смешиваю, а анализирую отдельно. Впрочем,  у нас такие разные взгляды, что лучше нам не пересекаться. Жаль, но это так, и я постараюсь больше не комментировать Ваши ответы.